# Use of oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, google-oauth

I have written a free-to-use psychotherapy website.  It uses my gmail address to send each user a password.  I have therefore set my gmail account to work with 'less secure apps'.
That setting will no longer be available from May so i need to use oauth 2.0 to make my website into a secure app.  But when i read about it, it states that the website user needs to grant access to the google account. This confuses me for two reasons

1. it's MY account, not the site user's account
2. I am horribly ignorant about internet systems
   I'd be very grateful for any advice or comments but please could you express it in the simplest language possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize an App Password instead if your gmail has 2-Step Verification enabled.

[Google Support page for App Passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Thank you for answering.  So i'm assuming that you're not referring to my gmail account password.  Is it a new password that i set up for communication between my website and my gmail account?

Comment: Yep! Google is disabling the ability to login with your regular account password from 3rd party apps. But once you’ve turned on 2-Step Verification for your account, it gives you the option to generate a single-use 16 digit passcode to allow a specified app (or site or whatever) access to your account. 

OAuth 2.0 is ideal, but because not everybody is ready or able to integrate it yet, App Passwords provide a level of security without completely denying access for “less secure” apps.

Comment: Thank you SO much - that sounds much more suited to my level of ability.  I'm just wondering how the single-use aspect works as there will keep being different users needing to receive passwords?

Comment: By single-use I mean only the designated app is allowed to use it—apologies for not being clear. I recently had to switch to App Passwords for a couple of sites I host (after panicking about the less-secure-app shutdown and oauth integration hahah). One of the sites emails a password to an account holder when they register, and all is working well so far :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm very grateful - you even managed to use language that i understand!!  Sadly apparently i don't have enough experience on the site yet to show how helpful your answer has been.  Happy programming, Jinny

Comment: hiya, I'm back again sadly.  I'm not succeeding with app password approach.  I went into google account and turned on two-step verification and set up an app password for my website.  I defined it by the website address that I type to open the site.  I then typed the app password into my 'send email from website' programme as the password.  Sadly no email has been sent.

Comment: Hmm. What program are you using to send email? Are there error logs available?

Comment: Hi c0mpuk3!  I've been moving the programme to a new environment in the hope that I'd get an error log.  And presto, it worked in the new environment!  So I know that I've set it up correctly now and will fiddle away, as one does, till it works in the original environment.   I'm very impressed that you can repair things just by asking for an error log :-)

Comment: Hah! Great to hear that it's working in the new environment. It definitely took me a bit of fiddling to get it working right for each of the various sites I run. Error logs are my best friend lol!